# Can you create a DC replication partner with different versions of Windows Server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, domain-controller

We currently have three servers, two running 2008 r2 and one running 2012.

These servers currently run separate Domains. I would like to operate a single domain across a VPN. Is it possible to have the windows servers in the branch offices act as replication partners across the VPN and still provide domain services?

Also, what happens to DNS when they are on different subnets?

Comment: It's possible, but please check your forest and domain functional levels. 
Although different domains is a whole completely different story, and you should think what you want to do with that: do you want to merge them? Do you want a trust relationship?

Comment: @curropar I would like to have a single domain name across all three sites. So I would assume that means merging them.

Comment: Well, then you've a lot of work ahead of you! The good news is you'll learn a lot ;-)  There's not a solution for you, each case is different, and you'll have to literate yourself for this. You could start here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc974335(v=ws.10).aspx Good luck!!

Comment: You can't merge separate AD forests/domains. You can migrate users and computers from one domain to another or you can create forest trusts between the forests, but you can't merge them.

Comment: @joeqwerty so if I migrate a user, will their local desktop files etc change? Can they just login as if they are on the new domain and still have the same local profile?

Comment: Sure, @joeqwerty is right, technically the right word is migration. But I said "merge" as in "to have a single domain name across all three sites". If you do the migration right, users will end having their desktop in the new domain. But maybe a trust relationship between the domains is a good solution while you plan a migration.